# Should root account have password?

Tags: password, root

I have a headless server (CentOS 6.7 in my case).

Presumably in almost all circumstances commands issued as root should use sudo.

Is it possible, and wise, to completely disable password access for root?  I know this is the default policy for, say, an Ubuntu desktop box, but I'm not sure it's the right choice in most cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are *very few* instances when you need to use a `root` shell for anything. In fact, the only time I find myself at an actual `root` shell prompt is those few times when I'm configuring a new user for myself when setting up a new system.

The Ubuntu way of doing things, i.e. to [lock the `root` account completely](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo), is IMHO a good idea.

This is not the same as having a `root` account with an empty password, which would be a truly terrible idea.

The downside with `sudo` is that it's potentially difficult to configure for a novice, if anything other than "give some users full `root` access" is needed on a multi user system.

Comment: Curious. How does maintenance mode work on a system with a locked root account?

Comment: @roaima My Unix drops me into a root `sh` prompt upon booting single-user. Most Linuxes I know of will do the same, or can be done to do the same by giving the right boot parameters. If you have physical access to the machine, you have access to a `root` shell prompt in my experience.

Comment: @Kusalananda _This is not the same as having a root account with no password..._: I assume you mean that the root account should not have an empty password.

Comment: @user1071847 Yes. I will make it clearer.

Comment: There was a person on the Ubuntu SE who was very sad when his `root` had no password.   He had set his main user to use `zsh`, and then uninstalled the zsh package.  He had no other accounts who could `su` or `sudo` than his main one

Comment: @infixed Booting single-user and changing the user's login shell from there would fix it.

Comment: @Kusalananda  I don't remember if that got suggested.  All I know is suggesting that you use the guest facility and escape from the guest jail by using a `ssh` to loopback ( to allow `su`) gets you downvoted to oblivion quickly